# String Rotation

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, programming-challenge, strings

I have solved a previous year question of 2018 codevita ([link](https://www.programminggeek.in/2018/08/codevita-2018-round-1-question-string-rotation.html)) in Python.

**Problem Description:**

> Rotate a given String in the specified direction by specified magnitude.
>   After each rotation make a note of the first character of the rotated String, After all rotation are performed the accumulated first character as noted previously will form another string, say `FIRSTCHARSTRING`.
>   Check If `FIRSTCHARSTRING` is an Anagram of any substring of the Original string.
>   If yes print "YES" otherwise "NO".

Here is the code:

```
from collections import Counter

def lrotate(input,d): 
    Lfirst = input[0 : d] 
    Lsecond = input[d :] 

    return (Lsecond + Lfirst) 

def rrotate(input,d):
    Rfirst = input[0 : len(input)-d] 
    Rsecond = input[len(input)-d : ] 

    return (Rsecond + Rfirst)


s=input()
n=int(input())
c='FIRSTCHARSTRING'
l=[]
for _ in range(n):
    w,v=input().split()
    v=int(v)
    if w == 'L':
        p=lrotate(c,v)
    if w == 'R':
        p=rrotate(c,v)
    l.append(p[0])

if Counter(l) == Counter(s) :
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

What can I do to optimize my code?

Comment: What is/are your goal/s in `optimize my code`? Your implementation tries to stick to the letter of the task description (which is a good thing at least for a reference for correctness) - you might go for *readability*, *maintainability*, *acceptable result using least resources* (including coder time) or *exact result using least machine resources* or…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python `deque` function to rotate string.

```
word = 'FIRSTCHARSTRING'
commands = [
  ('L', 2),
  ('R', 3),
  ('L', 1),
]

from collections import deque

q = deque(word)

for direction, magnitude in commands:
  if direction == 'L':
    q.rotate(-magnitude)
  else:
    q.rotate(magnitude)

if ''.join(q) == word:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```